# Ansible lookup url with proxy

Tags: proxy, ansible, environment-variables

How can I use ansible lookup url with a proxy (in environment) at task level, this doesn't seem to work:

```
- debug: 
    msg: "{{ lookup('url','https://website', use_proxy=True) }}"
  environment:
     https_proxy: "https://user:pass@proxy:8080/"
```

I am able to run it successfully with:

```
https_proxy="https://user:pass@proxy:8080/" ansible-playbook play.yml
```

But I need to set the proxy at the task level (or block level)

Comment: @VladimirBotka `environment` in a task, even if played on localhost, will not affect a lookup which is played directly from ansible(-playbook) process on the controller and is only affected by the initial environment on the controller. As a POC (created with a `pipe` lookup but `uri` behaves exactly the same) see https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/74387a147f8da3ac911c2769927cb00b. I'm prettry sure OP''s requirement is impossible to acheive: vars must be set in controller environment and cannot be at task level.

Comment: You're right. `environment` has no effect in `lookup`. In addition to `pipe` and `uri`, I've tested with the `env` plugin.